# I can send a notification from the Firebase Console, but I can not send it via php

Tags: php, firebase, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

Server key is true
I have tried separately with the old server key and the key for the new server, it has not happened.
I'm sending notification to a single device using a token from Firebase console, it works.
I send it to all devices, it works.

When I send it with php the notification does not appear on emulator and phone

php shows this result
curl result: 
"success":3
"failure":0
"canonical_ids":0"

where is the problem?

FcmMessasingService

```js
package com.package.name;

import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;

import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;

public class FcmMessagingService extends com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService{

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

        showNotification(remoteMessage.getData().get("message"));
    }

    private void showNotification(String message) {

        Intent i = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,i,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentTitle("FCM")
                .setContentText(message)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        manager.notify(0,builder.build());
    }


}
```

php file

```html
<?php

 function send_notification ($tokens, $message)
 {

  $url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
  $fields = array(
    'registration_ids' => $tokens,
    'data' => $message
   );

  $headers = array(
   'Authorization:key = AAAA7hSYiy0:APA91bHxEnClm7FnCHFF72N9YraNUatKv1n4UsZwoNH6AWJ_n7O4Ixbmq71jFVJ_6vLC_q4Aq_AMh4O_qGYxbp35XL7vzRyD7B6JUK9bWSBNQYhQ-SxZzJ5_7URJEmyJc2Y4fGmzK-pi',
   'Content-Type: application/json'
   );

    $ch = curl_init();
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
       curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
       $result = curl_exec($ch);
       if ($result === FALSE) {
           die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
       }
       curl_close($ch);
       return $result;
 }


 $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","token_table");
  $sql = " Select token from token_table";

 $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
 $tokens = array();

 if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0 ){

  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   $tokens[] = $row["token"];
  }
 }

 mysqli_close($conn);

 $message = array("message" => "THIS IS TEST MESSAGE");
 $message_status = send_notification($tokens, $message);
 echo $message_status;

print_r($tokens);

 ?>
```

return $result and $tokens

```html
{"multicast_id":8903891154922407840,"success":3,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1512509834754831%01f815b6f9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1512509834755366%01f815b6f9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1512509834754833%01f815b6f9fd7ecd"}]}Array ( [0] => cWdBtAg-0ok:APA91bEeXBTdJqDXvYOrVR-ZacwCGzDDCVhLodfNjw-D9_YSxMSXbZNixZNAE7oZsCnFGguECytcNZWPMujiUj_A6BExccCo2U9-nuURB-PME4L27pOceNBhq52DLkU7JqcP4yMjWCnQ [1] => fzvOmSJDvwE:APA91bEWqamnklzY0QvRNDz9fI0CJehpwVAHmIdBFXovDMpmJqr5DEm3bIYdIALlwb2u53wuMtOMf2TdTQTj5LTlAIpeFnbnmXK7Q6f_j-k2mEcduwdRvjs2nQ5yw-TwkKY1HNfIy6jb [2] => dtMH2ehN-Bg:APA91bF6Zr9wYlWArvsjs-bu8c275HfaijbNz07prTWBaT8CYqclaaIjbXRq4tpWvqI8IdGIZomu3QjtjYOsbyFpPZiAoG2mX6fbadmRstgbE8-dVtdOW3RNblYLW3m1lkmcYIEMGI-q )
```